# How can i fix this render issue?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have some problem with rendering. When I render it renders like this
[image: Rendered in image editor at Frame 26]

But When I take a preview blender it looks good, like this;
[image: Rendered in preview at Frame 26]

If you want the blend file: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hpMcWhKtvQQWQ2NUtXd0x1Sk0/view?usp=sharing)

Sorry if you do not understand

The frame you need to see = 26, 32 34-36 and more

Anyway please help me

Comment: when you attach the blend file attach here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad topology: essenciatlly non-manifold vertices and duplicated vertices.
It is noticeable in frame 32. If you disable the modifiers, change to solid mode, you will see the strange artifacts on the surface. I tried to dissolve the non-manifold vertexes and to remove double vertexes, then recalculate the normals, and problem is only slightly fixed. On my advise, the fastest way to fix, will be with retopology: you have to remake the head, but this time, you have to try to keep a simple geometry. Try to see some tutorials on how to do retopology faster. If you are in a hurry, and don't have time to do it correctly, you can cheat it by: while in edit mode > press T to open left menu, go to "shading/Uv's" tab> on shading the faces, select flat> press N to open the right menu > press A once or twice to select all the object> on the N menu, under Tranform tab, on edges data, decrease the "mean crease" to 0, and try a render (worked for me). Yet, if I were you, I would consider retopology in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, your .blend file looked OK when I rendered it here.

I suspect you have to flip normals.
Edit mode > Mesh > Faces > Recalculate Normals

Comment: I've downloaded it too and it looks also fine to me. I even checked frame 26 as in the screenshot. There are no strange artefacts.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not happen.

Comment: @Brain I use blender 2.78, What version do you have?

Comment: It looks fine for me too.

Comment: I use 2.79 which is now 2 weeks old (not the stable version).